# Blender 2.78a takes ages to import models, reacts slow and freezes on import

Tags: import

I have installed latest windows updates including Nividia driver. Ever since I upgraded blender, windows and drivers (automatic update) blender 2.78a takes up to 20 minutes to open models in mainly .obj formats but also other formats like Collada etc. Opens start window but as soon as I am trying to import any model blender is "not responding" for ages. Once it managed to open the model after a long time, I can hardly work with it as it keeps freezing and stuttering, blinking etc. I tried just about anything from re-install, deleting blender foundation folders all the way to go back to to previous version with no results.

Any help is highly appreciated as I really like the program but as it stands are absolutely unable to do anything with it.

Asus UX51VZA - Windows 10 64b
Install Path: "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
Intel Core I7 - 3612QM - CPU 2.1GHZ - 4 cores - Driver version 10.18.10.4425
Nividia 650M - 8GB RAM - Driver version:376.33
Intel HD Graphics 4000

Tnx in advance.

Comment: maybe related?:http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family